# Is there any way to capture full screen screenshot in appium

Tags: java, appium

I am using appium and java for mobile automation .

I am aware of taking screenshot using below code which is given on appium website

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

But this Only capture the screen visible on phone it will not capture the content which is not visible on screen. I have to capture the full screen screenshot which user can view by scrolling down on same screen.

One approach is to scroll the screen and then capture screenshot but it will result in multiple screenshot of same screen. I am looking to integrate full screen in a single image .

We can do this in webdriver using [ASHOT](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot) but I have no idea on how to do it in Appium. Any reference would be helpful .

Thanks

Comment: Android basically displays only the screen that is visible on that particular moment. Even UIautomator parses the xml for the visible portion of the screen

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score -3):

Below is code from official documentation to take screenshot. Check this:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

For more information you can visit their [official site](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/#example-usage).

Comment: this will capture only visible screen on the phone. It will not capture the whole screen.